# Groovy startup failed unexpected token

Tags: groovy

Excuse me if this is a silly question, I'm a complete Groovy noob and I'm tearing my hair out.

Trying to run an example groovy script:

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def csv = '''Name:Lastname
Mark:Andersson
Pete:Hansen'''

def data = parseCsv(csv, autoDetect:true)
for(line in data) {
    println "$line.Name $line.Lastname"
}
```

And getting the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, /home/kmcghee/groovy/dev/import_csv/test: 2: unexpected token: import @ line 2, column 1.
   import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv
```

I've googled a lot on this and it appears to be related to Grapes but I can't pin down the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you paste that code in?  Can you try retyping the first two lines?  It might be a weird quote char throwing the parser off...  (maybe)

Comment: Your code runs flawlessly for me... (running Groovy 2.3.8)

Comment: works in groovy 2.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. After noting the versions you guys are using I updated to the latest and it now works. 'apt-get install' gave me 1.8 and I hadn't checked. Schoolboy.